# AEM - org.apache.sling.jcr.resource.internal.JcrResourceResolverFactoryImpl

Tags: aem

I made one line change to URL mapping section in Apache sling resource resolver factory and clicked on saved button, changes are not reflecting.  I was able to save it before, don't know what happens now. Please help me if anybody have seen this issue  and resolved it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post it there? This change.

Comment: Not only with adding.. Tried by removing existing url mapping.. Still changes are not saving..basically save function not working even if i add and delete something in the url mapping section

Comment: How many entries do you have there? If you have a lot, than your request can be too big. Can you check response from the CQ in developer console of your browser?

Comment: +1, @Alex. Please see what is printed in error.log. Paste the error.log here when you save the configuration.